# Sqlite3 slow UPDATE

Tags: performance, sqlite, subtraction

I have this huge (8 GB/14126762 rows) with two tables, table1 (very big) and table2 (much smaller) on which I need to reduce a value from table1 using table2 vakyes.

While I did some tests using a smaller database(5MB database), it was fine. But now, when i use it on the bigger database, it takes forever and I don't know if it works at all.

For instance, it takes 12 mins to create the database with INSERT command.

The troublesome transaction is the following:

```
UPDATE table1
   SET vl_empenho = vl_empenho - 
     (SELECT vl_estorno 
     FROM table2 WHERE table1.cd_ugestora = 
     table2.cd_ugestora AND table1.dt_ano = 
     table2.dt_ano AND table1.nu_empenho = 
     table2.nu_empenho) 
   WHERE cd_ugestora IN (SELECT table2.cd_ugestora FROM 
     table2 WHERE table1.dt_ano =
     table2.dt_ano AND table1.nu_empenho =
     table2.nu_empenho);
```

I´m not proficient on Sqlite and the transaction gave what I wanted, but I don't know if it redundant.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: are your relations indexed?  If not, probably good to index before updating

Comment: I index only the following, should I index the others? 
CREATE INDEX MyLittleIndex ON table1(vl_empenho);
CREATE INDEX MyLittleIndex2 ON table2(vl_estorno);

Comment: Are you storing your sqlite file on a local or network drive?

Comment: I´m storing on a SSD drive locally.

Comment: Edit into your question the complete schema (`CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX`) commands. Also use `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN <query>` to see how SQLite will execute your query. The two indexes you mentioned in the comments are useless for this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comments and other stackoverflow related question, I made a index for each columns on the query, also I set:

```
PRAGMA synchronize = OFF; 
PRAGMA jorunal_mode = MEMORY;
```

With that, i took about 20mins to do the UPDATE above mentioned and 6 mins for the INSERT command, which I find appropriate, considering the filesize(actually 10gb).

Thanks for all the attention!

EDIT: Regarding the comment from David Stein it is TRUE! You cant easily corrupt your database with these options. On my case, it was a very replaceable rebuidable database with no sensitive data. I rebuild it anytime I wanted and I was its only user. So I needed it blazing-fast! 
Maybe it´s not your situation.

Comment: WARNING: DON'T DO THIS. Setting journal_mode = MEMORY poses a risk of corrupting a SQLite database. See the official SQLite page entitled "How to Corrupt a Database," item #7 ("SQLite Configuration Errors") for more info.